# Get the line before pattern that won't match pattern

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a file with the following lines

```
4278.82888126 , 17 , 17 , 0
4289.29672647 , Marker 1
4478.07865548 , 18 , 18 , 0
5289.84818625 , 19 , 19 , 0
5377.07618618 , Marker 2
5505.54010463 , 20 , 20 , 0
5869.55748796 , 21 , 20 , 1
6057.54284048 , 22 , 20 , 2
6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
6455.30569553 , Marker 3
7594.11082244 , Marker 4
```

For every Marker, I need a valid line (not a Marker line) that is right before it.
I tried with

```
grep -B1 "Marker" file | grep -v Marker | grep -v '\-\-'
```

But that did not give me a line for every marker. 
It seems to be an easy one but how do I get the following lines?

```
 4278.82888126 , 17 , 17 , 0
 5289.84818625 , 19 , 19 , 0
 6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
 6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
```

Comment: Why is this tagged python? Are you looking for a solution in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just store lines in a variable and if the line containing marker is found, print the variable.

```
$ awk '/Marker/ && line { print line; next } { line = $0 }' file
4278.82888126 , 17 , 17 , 0
5289.84818625 , 19 , 19 , 0
6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
```

- `/Marker/ && line` is an action which tests if the line contains `Marker` and if the variable `line` is set. If it is then it prints the variable.
- `next` allows us to move to the next line so we don't end up storing the current line containing `Marker` in our variable.
- For all lines that do not contain `Marker` we keep storing in a scalar variable to be printed later on.

Comment: can you explain us plz

Comment: Thanks @Hackaholic for leaving a comment. I have added some explanation. Please let me know if there is anything in particular you would like me to elaborate on.

Answer (score 0):

Using python , its simple :

```
>>> import re
>>> f = open('ll.txt')
>>> prev = f.next().strip()
>>> for x in f:
...     if re.search('Marker',x) and not re.search('Marker',prev):
...         print prev
...     else: prev = x.strip()
... 
4278.82888126 , 17 , 17 , 0
5289.84818625 , 19 , 19 , 0
6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
6161.77394795 , 23 , 20 , 3
```

Comment: what about if we have 3 or more line that contain `Marker` ?